# UpdateHandler, do a thing only when trigger is true, Android

Tags: java, android, handler

I have a handler that receives a message on every location update, every 5 secs. From the location I can request the current city the user is moving in. Then I want to download some data once and only when city changes. How can I realize that?

```
Handler myViewUpdateHandler = new Handler(){

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE_LOCATION:
                mc.animateTo(geosenseo.getCurrentPoint());  
                mapView.invalidate();

                    //a async task sets the currentCity field   

               if(trigger && (currentCity != "")){
                   firstCity = currentCity;
                   trigger = false;
               }

               if((currentCity != "") && (firstCity != "")){
                   if(firstCity != currentCity){
                       //download only when city changes
                       trigger = true;
                   } 
               }

           }

            super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

like you can see I have played around with the vars. any ideas? thanks

Comment: How do you get the current City from the Location?

Comment: in the code that is marked with //a async task sets the currentCity field I start an asynctask, that in the background downloads some geodata, in this case the city, I use geocoder from

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped...compare strings with equals and the following if statement

```
if(!currentCity.equals("")){
    if(!firstCity.equals(currentCity)){
      firstCity = currentCity;
    }
}
```